# How to patch themes files to get custom themes working?

Tags: windows-7, themes

I'm on Windows 7 build 7601 x64, and I've tried everything to patch my `uxtheme.dll`, `themeservice.dll`, `themeui.dll` with different patchers – like Universal Theme Patcher – but nothing helps.

I am restoring the original files with

```
sfc /scannow
```

and try patching again, but it doesn't change. When I try to activate a custom theme, it opens the default Aero theme.

Comment: Please note: Every time I messed around with such themes, I messed up my Windows. So ... you may want to do a complete backup before you start patching. Or just use WindowsBlinds.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [UxStyle](http://www.uxstyle.com/); it should work for you.

Comment: Can you describe the linked content, and how it relates to the question? This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the link becomes invalid.  In addition, please be careful posting links in answers of this nature--they could be seen by the community as spam, correctly or otherwise.  See the [FAQ#promotion] for more information.